# why is this html5 audio not working on chrome, but is work well on safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, web-audio-api

i want play some voice on my web, and this is my code ,it's work on safari, but cat't work on chrome. anybody could give me a solution

```
$(button).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "messageaction",
            type : "post",
            dataType : "xml",
            cache : false,
            data : {
                message : "msg_askmessg",
                os : KHL_parameter.os,
                usertype : KHL_parameter.usertype,
                ver : KHL_parameter.ver,
                messageid : msgid,
                type : 2
            }
        }).done(function(responsedata) {
            var source = context.createBufferSource(); 
            var buffer = context.createBuffer($.processStreamVoice(responsedata), true); //$.processStreamVoice, is base64 decode for responsedata
            source.buffer = buffer; 
            source.connect(context.destination); 
            source.noteOn(context.currentTime);
        });
    });
```

Comment: where is the object "context" defined?  This looks more like a jQuery question to me, as there is to html5 audio code presented.

Comment: 'var mycontext;
 if (window.webkitAudioContext) {
  mycontext = new webkitAudioContext();
 } else if (window.AudioContext) {
  mycontext = new AudioContext();
 }'

Comment: i have defined it, it's not a jQuery question, context.creatByffer(), this code will dead with a error, An invalid or illegal string was specified.

Comment: So you define it as "mycontext", but call it as "context"?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
 source.noteOn(context.currentTime);
```

to this:

```
source.noteOn ? source.noteOn(0) : source.start(0);
```

The `noteOn` method has been replaced by `start`, but Safari hasn't caught up yet. And the argument of `0` is equivalent to `context.currentTime` -- both will start playing immediately.